# Grails 3.2 - defaultAction ignored on scaffolded controllers?

Tags: grails, grails-3.2

Curious if this is an issue or if I'm doing something wrong.  Given the following controller:

```
class MetaDataTypeController {
  static scaffold = MetaDataType
  static defaultAction = 'list'

  def list() {
    render("You meant ${g.link(action: 'index', '/index')}")
  }

  def index() {
    [metaDataTypeList: MetaDataType.list()]
  }
}
```

accessing the application at "/app/metaDataType", I would expect to see the "list" action, with a link to "index".  What I see is the "index" action.  If I remove the `static scaffold` declaration, it works and I'm shown the link.

Is this intentional?  Am I just overlooking something.

Edit: typo fixed

Answer (score 0):

Do as like that

```
class MetaDataTypeController {
  static scaffold = MetaDataType

  def index() {
        redirect(controller:'MetaDataType',action:'list')
    }

  def list() {
        [metaDataTypeList: MetaDataType.list()]
    }
```

Comment: That technically works, but the example was illustrative...  I don't want the scaffolded `index() ` action to redirect to `list()`.  In real life, those are two separate things, and I want list to be the default action while still leveraging the scaffolded index.